# Mail chimp listSubscribe wrapper function c#

Tags: c#, mailchimp

I have a method in Mail chimp v1.1 class

```
 [XmlRpcMethod("listSubscribe")]

 //bool listSubscribe(string apikey, string id, string email_address, Hashtable mv, string email_type, bool double_optin);
```

which I replaced with

```
bool listSubscribe(string apikey, string id, string email_address, array merge_vars, string email_type, bool double_optin, bool update_existing, bool replace_interests, bool send_welcome);
```

Now it gives me error The type or namespace name 'array' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

What should I write in the C# wrapper file for "**array** merge_vars" parameter.

Answer (score 1):

```
     /**
     ** listSubscribe method definitions
     **/
    public bool listSubscribe(string id, string email_address){
        return this.listSubscribe(id, email_address, new MCMergeVar[0]);
    }
    public bool listSubscribe(string id, string email_address, MCMergeVar[] merges){
        return this.listSubscribe(id, email_address, merges, "html");
    }
    public bool listSubscribe(string id, string email_address, MCMergeVar[] merges, string email_type){
        return this.listSubscribe(id, email_address, merges, email_type, true);
    }
    public bool listSubscribe(string id, string email_address, MCMergeVar[] merges, string email_type, bool double_optin){
        //XmlRpcStruct mv = this.mergeArrayToStruct(merges);
        return this.listSubscribe(id, email_address, merges, email_type, double_optin, false);
    }
    public bool listSubscribe(string id, string email_address, MCMergeVar[] merges, string email_type, bool double_optin, bool update_existing)
    {
        XmlRpcStruct mv = this.mergeArrayToStruct(merges);
        return this.api.listSubscribe(this.apikey, id, email_address, mv, email_type, double_optin, update_existing, true, false);
    }

   [XmlRpcMethod("listSubscribe")]
    //bool listSubscribe(string apikey, string id, string email_address, Hashtable mv, string email_type, bool double_optin);
    bool listSubscribe(string apikey, string id, string email_address, Hashtable merge_vars, string email_type, bool double_optin, bool update_existing, bool replace_interests, bool send_welcome);
```